# Exchange Web Services - how to load the Mime Content Type property of an item attachment

Tags: c#, email, email-attachments, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to run the below code to write an item that is an email attachment to a file on disk but it gives an error because the property is not loaded.

```
using (Stream FileToDisk = new FileStream(emailAttachmentsPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    itemAttachment.Load(
    byte[] ContentBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(itemAttachment.ContentType);

    FileToDisk.Write(ContentBytes, 0,ContentBytes.Length);
    FileToDisk.Flush();
    FileToDisk.Close();
}
```

I have tried this but it won't compile:

```
email.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent));
```

how can I get the item Content type so I can create my `ContentBytes` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the end I did this (basically I needed to load the Mimi content of the *ietem* attachment, plus some extra properties:

```
itemAttachment.Load(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties));

itemAttachment.Load(new PropertySet(
        BasePropertySet.IdOnly,
        ItemSchema.Subject,
        ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived,
        ItemSchema.DisplayTo, 
        EmailMessageSchema.From, EmailMessageSchema.Sender,
        EmailMessageSchema.HasAttachments, ItemSchema.MimeContent,
        EmailMessageSchema.Body, EmailMessageSchema.Sender,
        ItemSchema.Body) { RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text });

string BodyText = itemAttachment.Item.Body.Text;

string itemAttachmentName = itemAttachment.Name.Replace(":", "");

// Put attachment contents into a stream. 
emailAttachmentsPath = emailAttachmentsPath + "\\" + itemAttachmentName +  ".eml";
var mimeContent = itemAttachment.Item.MimeContent;

//save to disk 
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(emailAttachmentsPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    fileStream.Write(mimeContent.Content, 0, mimeContent.Content.Length);
}
```

another option:

```
var mimeContent2 = itemAttachment.Item.MimeContent;
byte[] ContentBytes = mimeContent2.Content;

//convert array of bytes into file
FileStream objfileStream = new FileStream("C:\\email2case\\temp\\testing" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss") + ".eml", FileMode.Create);
objfileStream.Write(ContentBytes, 0, ContentBytes.Length);
objfileStream.Close();
```

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: This code does two `Load()` calls which result in web service calls to EWS. You're better off making one `Load()` call with all the properties you want. (Unless that's not possible in this case, if so why not?)  Also beware of other non-valid filename characters in item names. Best to loop through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx and replace them all.

Answer (score 2):

```
itemAttachment.Load(new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.MimeContent));
var mimeContent2 = itemAttachment.Item.MimeContent;
fileBytes = mimeContent2.Content;
```